# Is Ubuntu One available for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-one

I want to sync files to the cloud in Ubuntu but I cannot do it using Google Drive or OneDrive, instead I have to manually upload them.

I found Ubuntu One, but I can't find any way to install it.  How do I install it?

Comment: Ubuntu One is closed for 'cloud file' functions; it continues on only as a one-stop login for Ubuntu services - refer https://login.ubuntu.com/one-redirect

Answer (score 1):

No, Ubuntu One file sync isn't available anymore.

It closed down 4 years ago:
https://blog.ubuntu.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services

I would suggest looking at [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) if you're a newer user or [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) if you're more advanced.